# ROS1 catkin_make failed: catkin_install_python() called without required DESTINATION argument

Tags: python, windows, cmake, ros

I tried to add python scripts to my packages reference this two tutorials.

[Handling of setup.py](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html)

[Installing Python scripts and modules](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html)

So I added setup.py in root `test\src\test_pkg`, changed CMakeLists.txt in path `test\src`. (My package root path is `test\`, and my package path is `test\src\test_pkg`, my python scripts path is `test\src\test_pkg\scripts`)

This is setup.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup


setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['test_pkg'],
    scripts=['/scripts'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'}
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

This is CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test_pkg)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  message_generation
)

catkin_python_setup()

catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS scripts/talker
                      DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

add_message_files(
  FILES
  Num.msg
)

add_service_files(
  FILES
  AddTwoInts.srv
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime sensor_msgs

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

install(PROGRAMS 
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Then I run `catkin_make` in path `test`.(I have run `test\devel\setup.bat`)
And got this CMake error:

```
Base path: E:\workspace\ros\test
Source space: E:\workspace\ros\test\src
Build space: E:\workspace\ros\test\build
Devel space: E:\workspace\ros\test\devel
Install space: E:\workspace\ros\test\install
####
#### Running command: "nmake cmake_check_build_system" in "E:\workspace\ros\test\build"
####

Microsoft (R) ?????????ù??? 14.20.27508.1 ??
??????? (C) Microsoft Corporation??  ?????????????

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: E:/workspace/ros/test/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: E:/workspace/ros/test/devel;C:/opt/ros/melodic/x64;C:/opt/rosdeps/x64
-- This workspace overlays: E:/workspace/ros/test/devel;C:/opt/ros/melodic/x64
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: C:/opt/python27amd64/python.exe
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Using empy: C:/opt/python27amd64/lib/site-packages/em.pyc
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: E:/workspace/ros/test/build/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: C:/opt/python27amd64/Scripts/nosetests-2.7.exe
-- catkin 0.7.14
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Using CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES: test_pkg
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - test_pkg
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'test_pkg'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(test_pkg)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at C:/opt/ros/melodic/x64/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_install_python.cmake:20 (message):
  catkin_install_python() called without required DESTINATION argument.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  test_pkg/CMakeLists.txt:27 (catkin_install_python)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/workspace/ros/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/workspace/ros/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: ??C:\opt\rosdeps\x64\bin\cmake.exe??: ???????0x1??
Stop.
Invoking "nmake cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

How to fix this error? Thanks for any reply.

System: Windows10

ROS: ROS1

- /rosdistro: melodic
- /rosversion: 1.14.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, while `catkin` is a generic enough tool, it's typically used for the robotics framework ROS. So by asking on ROS' question community [answers.ros.org](https://answers.ros.org/questions/) you might get more response.

> ```
> CMake Error at C:/opt/ros/melodic/x64/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_install_python.cmake:20 (message):
>   catkin_install_python() called without required DESTINATION argument.
> ```

I think you referred to the right online resources. I've also looked at them and none of them clarified this, but `catkin_package()` needs to be called prior to `catkin_install_python`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct order is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test_pkg)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  message_generation
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  Num.msg
)

add_service_files(
  FILES
  AddTwoInts.srv
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime sensor_msgs

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

#catkin_python_setup()
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS scripts/talker
                      DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
)
```

But since you delete all the unused code, I am not sure whether I got it correct above. If it is in the original file, it should be here:

```
    ## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination)
#catkin_package()
#catkin_python_setup()
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS scripts/talker.py scripts/listener.py
        DESTINATION   ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Almost at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.
I thought you copy the code to the wrong position.
If you place those code in a relatively early position, you are possibly getting it wrong. Try to place the code here.

```
## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination)
#catkin_package()
#catkin_python_setup()
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS scripts/talker.py scripts/listener.py
        DESTINATION   ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```